# loading view controller embedded inside navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

Im trying to create a loading view controller before it loads my tableView. This works fine.

However when the tableView is displayed I get a back button. When clicked it takes me back to the loading view. Im guessing this is because its embedded inside of the navigation controller. Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to hide the back button just add

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
```

in the third View controller's viewDidLoad 
else add

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

Comment: I dont want to hide the navigation bar. I just dont want the back button to be there. Thanks

Comment: This worked but I understand its not the best way of having a loading view.

Answer (score 0):

Do not push the offers load view controller via navigationController, just subview its view on the offersviewcontroller (the third one) like this in the viewDidLoad method:

```
OffersLoadViewController *offerLoadView = [[OffersLoadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OffersLoadViewControllerv" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview: offerLoadView.view];
```

After dealing with loading just remove it:

```
[offerLoadView.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: This seems a good way. But when trying to do [offerLoadView removeFromSuperview]; after my processing I get "No visible @interface for 'OffersLoadViewController' declares the selector 'removeFromSuperView'"

Comment: My mistake. You should removeFromSuperView offerLoadView.view. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks the error has gone. At runtime its complaining that it cannot find bundle initWithNibName:@"OffersLoadViewControllerv". Any ideas?

Comment: Put the Name of the offerloadviewcontroller .xib there. Probably '@"OffersLoadViewController"' I just provided sample code :-)

Comment: I'm using a storyboard, not .xib files. Does that matter?

Comment: Would it just be OffersLoadViewController *offerLoadView = [[OffersLoadViewController alloc] init]; ?

Comment: `UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"mystoryboard"
                                              bundle:nil];
OffersLoadViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OffersLoadViewController"];`

Comment: Ok no errors which is great but my subview does not show, I just see a blank table view. Code is below. Please help.

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    
    UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    
    LoadingViewController* loadView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoadingView"];
    
    [self.view addSubview: loadView.view];
    
 // XML Parser Processing
    
    [loadView.view removeFromSuperview];
    
}

Thanks,

Comment: You should call this after the table is loaded with data. No you add it and at the same moment you remove it (in the next code line of adding it, you remove it).

Comment: Still struggling to understand how this works. Do you have any tutorials or sample code?

Comment: How do you load your table with data?

Comment: It loaded using an XML Parser. I want to have the loading screen appear while its doing the parsing and when its done the data will be displayed.

Comment: So you must put this [loadView.view removeFromSuperview] inside the delegate method that gets triggered when parser finishes parsing. Declare loadView as a property in your .h file, so you can refer to it anywhere in your class methods.

Comment: Im using a third party parser, RaptureXML so that may be pretty hard. I'll keep looking on the net

Answer (score 0):

You have different options to choose from, depending on your needs:

- The loading view can push the navigation controller.
- You could avoid using a full view controller to do your loading, and instead just set a view above the rest of your "offers view controller".
- Or, refers to Raon answers if you just want the button to disappear

Comment: What do you mean by set a view above the rest of your "offers view controller".

Answer (score 0):

The navigation controller will keep all the controllers that you pushed in a navigation stack.

So if you push ladingviewcontroller using navigation controller and then pushing tableview controller the navigation stack will contain both the controllers and thats why on pressing back button, you are navigated to loadingViewController.

What I suggest is to remove loadingviewcontroller and show loading view in your tableviewcontroller before loading the tableview. Like, in viewWillAppear of tableviewcontroller, just add a UIView with loading indicator and add it as a subview of tableviewcontroller and remove it after you are ready to show your tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to hide the back nav bar button, you can do this

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

But the better way to show the loading controller's view would be this,

```
[self.view addSubview:loadingController.view];
[loadingController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:loadingController];
[loadingController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

just hide it or remove it from `superView` when loading view is not required. You can even animate it while hiding so that it gives a nicer effect.

Comment: How would I do this step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a architecture issue, the best way is the following:

1. Make the 2 and 3 view a single one. I mean you must add the ActivityIndicator at the center of the view that contains the table view.
2. Make the table view hidden and `startAnimating` the `UIActivityIndicatorView`.
3. Do all your loading stuff.
4. When you finish loading, `stopAnimating` your `UIActivityIndicatorView` and make the table view visible again.

And that's it ;)

Comment: How would you do this?

Comment: put the tableView and the Activity indicator in the same view (the controller in the center) delete the 3rd view, create Outlets to the activity indicator and the table view, follow the steps 2, 3, 4. Not a big deal.